# Website always returning a <Response 403>

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, cloudflare, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to fetch html pages from a website (cardmarket) using the requests library, but I always get a 403 response. I point out that they added a "connection security check" page , which reappears every time I delete cookies. I think they just added Cloudflare.

I saw on the internet that it could be due to sent headers, and that it would be better to use proxies, but nothing changed. Here is the code I used (I use a file containing differents headers):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import yaml

with open("headers.yml") as f_headers:
    browser_headers = yaml.safe_load(f_headers)

proxy_list = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
proxy_list["url"] = "http://" + proxy_list["IP Address"] + ":" + proxy_list["Port"].astype(str)
print(proxy_list.head())

https_proxies = proxy_list[proxy_list["Https"] == "yes"]
https_proxies.count()

url = "https://httpbin.org/ip"
good_proxies = set()
headers = browser_headers["Chrome"]
for proxy_url in https_proxies["url"]:
    proxies = {
        "http": proxy_url,
        "https": proxy_url,
    }
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=2)
        good_proxies.add(proxy_url)
        print(f"Proxy {proxy_url} OK, added to good_proxy list")
    except Exception:
        pass


url = "https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic"
for browser, headers in browser_headers.items():
    print(f"\n\nUsing {browser} headers\n")
    for proxy_url in good_proxies:
        proxies = proxies = {
            "http": proxy_url,
            "https": proxy_url,
        }
        #print(requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=2))
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=2)
            print(response.json())
        except Exception:
            print(f"Proxy {proxy_url} failed, trying another one")
```

I'm new to scraping, so I don't understand why it keeps returning this response to me. Can someone explain why and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is struggling with this problem, I found a solution, using undetected_chromedriver, which I found [here](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/selenium-cloudflare-bypass#what-is-selenium).
Here's the code I use:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time 

text_file = open("output.txt", "w")

options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options) 
page = driver.get("https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Products/Singles/March-of-the-Machine/Ozolith-the-Shattered-Spire") 
driver.maximize_window() 
time.sleep(6)
html_code = driver.page_source  # get the HTML code of the page
text_file.write(html_code)  # write the HTML code to the text file
driver.save_screenshot("datacamp.png") 
driver.close()

text_file.close()
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only works when no captcha is shown.

Comment: I seem to always get a captcha in headless mode, but none in the regular mode.. any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

I have read your concern. Can you first check if the web site allows the use of proxies? I accessed their terms of use on this page: https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Policies/GeneralTermsAndConditions, and it seems to me that the site already offers APIs for third parties. Why do you want to use scraping when access to the API will be faster?
If web scraping is not illegal on this site, try **increasing the timeout** first.

I have Also realized that when accessing this site, I am not able to access the homepage directly due to security verification. This website may include proxy detection techniques. If it is not illegal, you can try using this tutorial, for example, to emulate a web browser on which you can perform captcha operations: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-bypass-Captcha-when-scraping.

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your reply. After many hours I found a solution, using undetected_chromedriver, which I found here: https://www.zenrows.com/blog/selenium-cloudflare-bypass#what-is-selenium. Also, they also say in their API documentation that they won't grant API access to every user, so I had no other way to retrieve the data.

Comment: Great  approach!